# Finding adverbs and what they modify using Stanford Parser

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working with the Stanford Parser and NLP software for the first time.

In my project, I would like to find all adverbs (such as "not" and "very") and determine they modify in a sentence.

For example, for the sentence "The book is not interesting", I can find the vertex for "not" in the parse tree. I would then like to find that "not" is modifying "interesting". Can the parser (or other Stanford corenlp software) provide that information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parse the sentence (for example "The book is not interesting") and you can see that "not" and "interesting" are at the same subtree. Similar information can be seen in the dependency tree.

Check it here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been using an approach like: "find the adverb in the tree, and then find the first adjective in the adverb's parent's right descendent." That seemed kind of hacky.

Comment: The link you gave me shows three "dependency" trees: basic dependencies, collapsed dependencies, and collapsed CC-processed dependencies. I'm not familiar with these trees. Which one do you think would be most useful to my problem? Thank you for any help.